# Валидация срабатывает только со второго раза JS

Tags: javascript

При нажатии на кнопку button, валидация срабатывает только со второго раза, при этом форма отправляется с первого раза если правильно все заполнить

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.form').submit(function() {
        $(this).validate({

        rules:{

        name: {
          required: true,
        },

        tell:{
          required: true,
        },

        email:{
          required: true,
          email: true,
        },
      },

      messages:{
        name :{
          required: "Это поле нужно заполнить",
        },

        tell:{
          required: "Это поле нужно заполнить",
          minlength: "Телефон не может быть короче 4 символов",
        },

        email:{
          required: "Это поле нужно заполнить",
          email: "Введите корректный адрес электронной почты",
        },
      },
    });
        var NameForm = $(this).attr('name');
    var r = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}
    [a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/;


    if (document[NameForm].name.value == '' || document[NameForm].tell.value == '' || !r.test(document[NameForm].email.value) ) {
            valid = false;
            return valid;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/vendor/feedback/mail.php",
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            $('.thank-you').fadeIn();//убирает дисплей нон с класса 
            $(this).find('input').val('');
      $('.form').trigger('reset');
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

P.S в JavaScript новичек, не судите строго

Comment: Я вот не пойму, чего людей не устраивает валидация предоставляемая html5? Все лепят js зачем-то. P.S. Это был риторический вопрос.

Comment: @Visman, например кастомизация сообщений об ошибках

Comment: @Visman например, из за скудной кастомизабельности и сложности (если вообще наличия возможности) стилизации

Answer (score 3):

У вас jquery-validate подключается к форме только после первого сабмита. Вам надо его подключить до того, как использовать. Например в $(document).ready :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.form').validate({
    rules:{
    name: {
      required: true,
    },
    tell:{
      required: true
   ...
```

А уже потом пользоваться.

P.S. людей все устраивает в html5 валидации, но вот заказчиков - не все. Например, почти всегда нужны кастомные сообщения об ошибках и, реже, кастомные правила валидации, которые не ограничиваются регекспами.

Comment: а там точно `$(this)` должно быть?

Comment: поправил. Спасибо за замечание!