# Почему форма отправляется только со второго клика?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте.
Как мне пофиксить скрипт, чтобы форма корректно отправлялась? Никак не могу понять, что не так.

```
$(".form").validate({
      rules: {
      name: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2,
          maxlength: 32
      },
      phone: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10
      }
    },
    messages: {
      name: {
          required: 'Заполните имя'
      },
      phone: {
        required: 'Заполните телефон'
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(".form").submit(function() { //Change
            var th = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mail.php", //Change
                data: th.serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                $('.form-phone').addClass('form-active-phone');
                th.trigger("reset");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('.form-phone').removeClass('form-active-phone');
                }, 3000);
                return false;
            });
            return false;
        });
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите строчку

```
$(".form").submit(function() { //Change
```

и соответствующую ей

```
});
```

То есть:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
  var th = $(form);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "mail.php", //Change
    data: th.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
    $('.form-phone').addClass('form-active-phone');
    th.trigger("reset");
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.form-phone').removeClass('form-active-phone');
    }, 3000);
  });
  return false;
}
```

Непонятны манипуляции с `'form-active-phone'` и `setTimeout`.

Comment: После этого форма не отправляется, а сайт переходит в начало документа, и в url добавляется куча инфы из формы.

Comment: Это не влияет на работу скрипта, а лишь добавляет внешних изменений для пользователя при успешной отправке.

Comment: Долго тупил, где-то все же была ошибка, а ваш скрипт помог. Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

У вас при первом клике происходит валидация формы и привязка к форме события onsubmit, а уже при втором клике происходит отправка.

Смотри: [Валидация срабатывает только со второго раза JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/726394/%D0%92%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-js)

Comment: Посмотрел и все равно не осознал.
submit вообще нужно вынести за пределы validate? не используя submitHandler.